# How to use List in endpoint exported by Spring Data REST?

Tags: java, rest, spring-data-rest

I have 2 objects, Foo and Bar (a Foo is @ManyToOne with Bar), and a very basic repository interface in Spring Boot 2.0, and a method:

```
   List<Foo> findByBarIn(@Param("bar") List<Bar> bar);
```

This gets mapped by Spring to an endpoint called /foos/search/findByBarIn

I can specify a single bar doing something like

GET http://host/foos/search/findByBarIn?bar=http://host/bars/33   (where 33 is the ID the of the Bar entity)

But, how can I specify multiple bars?

I've tried: (with no success)

GET http://host/foos/search/findByBarIn?bar=http://host/bars/33,http://host/bars/44

GET http://host/foos/search/findByBarIn?bar=http://host/bars/33&bar=http://host/bars/44

Comment: how is it relevant to Foo ? and is a requirement to do so via GET ?

Comment: Have you tried findByBarIn?bar=33&bar=44&bar=55? And change '@Param' to '@RequestParam'. Why don't you use Long instead of Bar (as you pass only id)?

Comment: I've tried also findByBarIn?bar=33&bar=44, it says "Parameter value element [1] did not match expected type [com.xxx.Bar (n/a)]"
Param is fine, as it works with only 1 bar; but I've tried also your suggestion and replaced with RequestParam and I've got this message:
 "message": "Unable to detect parameter names for query method com.xxx.FooRepository.findByBarIn! Use @Param or compile with -parameters on JDK 8."

Comment: It seems that you are passing a list of strings to your method parameter 'bar' redefine as : List<Foo> findByBarIn(@Param("bar") List<String> bar);
I'd also suggest that you follow Justas suggestion and only pass in the bar-ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out how to do it:

So, this prototype didn't work:

```
List<Foo> findByBarIn(@Param("bar") List<Bar> bars);
```

but this does:

```
List<Foo> findByBarIn(@Param("bar") Bar... bars);
```

And then, I can specify multiple bars by:

```
GET http://host/foos/search/findByBarIn?bar=http://host/bars/33&bar=http://host/bars/44
```