# How to use list parameter in JPA query with Spring Data Rest?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-rest

```
@Query("Select loc from Location loc where loc in :locations"
    )
    public Page<Location> searchLocations(List<Location> locations,
                                 Pageable pageable);
```

And then when the endpoint is called with

```
https://localhost:8080/api/v1/stores/search/searchLocations?locations=https://localhost:8080/api/v1/locations/23,https://localhost:8080/api/v1/locations/24
```

Only 24 is returned, not 23.

How do you actually supply a list parameter to the JPA query?

Comment: Have you tried: `locations=https://localhost:8080/api/v1/locations/23&locations=https://localhost:8080/api/v1/locations/24`

Comment: just tried. same problem

Comment: I know this works with the QueryDsl extension. Don't know if you have looked at that. Essentailly would give you query capability out of the box without having to create the search methods in the repository. Not answer, but maybe worth looking at....

Comment: Are you restricted to use `List<Location>` or it is possible to switch to an array `Location[]`?

Comment: Array is fine as long as there is a way to call the endpoint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/48504735/2201165 varargs works out of the box (if you would avoid the `Pageable` parameter). Because an array and varargs are pretty much the same and you also want to pass a `Pageable` to the method, I tried to use arrays:

You can change the parameter to `Location[] locations` so that the signature looks like this:

```
@Query("Select loc from Location loc where loc in :locations")
public Page<Location> searchLocations(Location[] locations, Pageable pageable);
```

With this, you are able to call the endpoint in the way @alan-hay mentioned in his comment:

```
curl -X GET "https://localhost:8080/api/v1/stores/search/searchLocations?locations=https://localhost:8080/api/v1/locations/24&locations=https://localhost:8080/api/v1/locations/23"
```

Here some SQL output to show what's executed:

```
Hibernate: select location0_.id as id1_0_ from location location0_ where location0_.id in (? , ?) limit ?
```

**Note**

Because you are able to access the locations via an own endpoint (`http://localhost:8080/api/v1/locations/{locationId}`) it is likely that there is an extra (Spring Data Rest) repository for the locations itself. In this case this is also possible:

```
public interface LocationRepository extends JpaRepository<Location, Long> {
  // Here you are also able to use Long[] instead of List<Long>
  public Page<Location> findByIdsIn(List<Long> ids, Pageable pageable);
}
```

With that, you can search the repository like this

```
curl -X GET "https://localhost:8080/api/v1/locations/search/findByIdsIn?ids=24,23"
```