# Enable HAL serialization in Spring Boot for custom controller method

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I'm trying to build a RESTful API with Spring Boot using spring-boot-starter-data-rest. There are some entities: accounts, transactions, categories and users - just the usual stuff.

When I retrieve the objects at http://localhost:8080/transactions via the API that has been generated by default, all is going well an I get a list with all transactions as JSON objects like that one:

```
{
  "amount": -4.81,
  "date": "2014-06-17T21:18:00.000+0000",
  "description": "Pizza",
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/transactions/5"
    },
    "category": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/transactions/5/category"
    },
    "account": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/transactions/5/account"
    }
  }
}
```

But now the goal is to retrieve only the latest transactions under that URL since I don't want to serialize the whole database table. So I wrote a Controller:

```
@Controller
public class TransactionController {
    private final TransactionRepository transactionRepository;

    @Autowired
    public TransactionController(TransactionRepository transactionRepository) {
        this.transactionRepository = transactionRepository;
    }

    // return the 5 latest transactions
    @RequestMapping(value = "/transactions", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<Transaction> getLastTransactions() {
        return  transactionRepository.findAll(new PageRequest(0, 5, new Sort(new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.DESC, "date")))).getContent();
    }
}
```

When I now try to access http://localhost:8080/transactions there's a

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed
```

because of the circular reference between users and accounts. When I solve this by adding a @JsonBackReference annotation to the account list in User, I can retrieve the transaction list but only with this "classic" format:

```
{
  "id": 5,
  "amount": -4.5,
  "date": "2014-06-17T21:18:00.000+0000",
  "description": "Pizza",
  "account": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Account Tilman",
    "owner": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Tilman"
    },
    "categories": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Groceries"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Restaurant"
      }
    ],
    "users": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Tilman"
      }
    ]
  },
  "category": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Restaurant"
  }
}
```

No HAL links anymore, everything is getting serialized directly by jackson. I tried adding

```
@EnableHypermediaSupport(type = HypermediaType.HAL)
```

to the entity classes but that didn't get me anywhere. I just want my controller to return the same objects that the generated API does, with HAL _links instead of every reference being serialized. Any thoughts?

**EDIT:**
OK, after thinking twice I realized that the @EnableHypermediaSupport annotation has to be added to the *configuration*, of course. This solves the problem of the circular references and I can remove the @JsonBackReference from User. But only the attributes of the object itself are being serialized, there is no _links section:

```
{
    "amount": -4.81,
    "date": "2014-06-17T21:18:00.000+0000",
    "description": "Pizza"
}
```

I know that I could write wrapper classes extending ResourceSupport for all my entities but this seems rather pointless. As spring-hateoas is able to magically generate the representations with the _link section for the REST interface that is created automatically there should be a way to return the same representations from a custom controller, right?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There's a lot of aspects here:

1. I doubt that the collection resource at `/transactions` really returns an individual transaction as you described. Those representations are returned for item resources.
2. If `TransactionRepository` already is a `PageableAndSortingRepository` the collection resource can be tweaked by expanding the URI template exposed in the API root for the link named `transactions`. By default that's a `page`, `size` and `sort` parameter. That means clients can request what you want to expose already.
3. If you want to default the paging and sorting options, implementing a controller is the correct way. However, to achieve a representation like Spring Data REST exposes you need to return at least instances of [`ResourceSupport`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/reference/html/#fundamentals.resources) as this is the type the HAL mapping is registered for.

   There's nothing magically here if you think about it. A plain entity does not have any links, the `ResourcesSupport` and types like `Resource<T>` allow you to wrap the entity and enrich it with links as you see fit. Spring Data REST basically does that for you using a lot of the knowledge about the domain and repository structure that's available implicitly. You can reuse a lot of as shown below.

   There are a few helper you need to be aware of here:

   - `PersistentEntityResourceAssembler` - which is usually injected into the controller *method*. It renders a single entity in a Spring Data REST way, which means that associations pointing to managed types will be rendered as links etc.
   - `PagedResourcesAssembler` - usually injected into the controller *instance*. Takes care of preparing the items contained in the page, optionally by using a dedicated `ResourceAssembler`.

   What Spring Data REST basically does for pages is the following:

   ```
   PersistentEntityResourceAssembler entityAssembler = …;
   Resources<?> … = pagedResourcesAssembler.toResources(page, entityAssembler);
   ```

   That's basically using the `PagedResourcesAssembler` with the `PersistentEntityResourceAssembler` to render the items.

   Returning that `Resources` instance should give you the representation design you expected.

Comment: That was very helpful, thanks! Is the `ResourcesSupport` documented anywhere?

Comment: Yes: http://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/reference/html/#fundamentals.resources

Comment: @OliverGierke Thank you very much, indeed! About your comments: (1.) Yes, the resource returns a list, of course. I just shortened the output in order to illustrate the format. (2.) Yes, I have a PagingAndSortingRepository but as you guessed, I want to (3.) provide and take away the possibility for the client to query the entire database table at once.

Comment: @OliverGierke Thanks again! It might be me, but I never considered looking for a Spring HATEOAS documentation. There is a footnote in the Spring Data REST documentation which I discovered just now. Maybe add a small section à la "If you want to create your own controller that integrates with HATEAOS, return `ResourcesSupport` and for details have a look at the Spring HATEAOS documentation"?

Comment: @Tilman You could also disable the export of the 'findAll()' method by annotating it with `@RestResource(exported = false)` and still use the query method.

Comment: @hzpz - Great idea! Care to file a ticket with our [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST)?

Comment: I'm having trouble to inject `PersistentEntityResourceAssembler`, it gives me "IllegalArgumentException: entities is marked @NonNull but is null". The same behavior was described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52790017/how-to-have-persistententityresourceassembler-injected-into-request-methods-of-c)

Comment: `PersistentEntityResourceAssembler` no longer works in Boot 2.3.x. It's current method toModel or toFullResource is producing a recursion error.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to create your own controller to limit query results or sort the results. Just create a [query method](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.details) in your repository:

```
public interface TransactionRepository extends MongoRepository<Transaction, String> {

    List<Transaction> findFirst10ByOrderByDateDesc();

}
```

Spring Data REST will automatically export it as a [method resource](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#repository-resources.query-method-resource) at `/transactions/search/findFirst10ByOrderByDateDesc`.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for! (The method name has to be findFirst10ByOrderByDateDesc() which makes the method resource available at http://localhost:8080/transactions/search/findFirst10ByOrderByDateDesc)

Answer (score 2):

To use PersistentEntityResourceAssembler in the controller we should mark it as @RepositoryRestController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/categories")
@RepositoryRestController
public class CategoryController implements ValidableController {

// dependencies

@RequestMapping(method = POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<PersistentEntityResource> create(@Valid @RequestBody CategoryForm category,
                                                       BindingResult validation,
                                                       PersistentEntityResourceAssembler resourceAssembler)
{
    validate(validation);
    Category entity = categoryConverter.convert(category);
    entity = categoryService.save(entity);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(resourceAssembler.toFullResource(entity));
}
```

It builds pretty nice HAL styled response

```
{
"createdTime": "2018-07-24T00:55:32.854",
"updatedTime": "2018-07-24T00:55:32.855",
"name": "cfvfcdfgdfdfdfs32",
"options": [
    "aaa",
    "bbb"
],
"_links": {
    "self": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/shop/categories/34"
    },
    "category": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/shop/categories/34{?projection}",
        "templated": true
    },
    "products": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/shop/categories/34/products"
    },
    "categories": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/shop/categories/34/categories{?projection}",
        "templated": true
    },
    "parent": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/shop/categories/34/parent{?projection}",
        "templated": true
    }
}
```

}